# How can I get a comma seperated value from XML to insert into the table in sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml

How can I get a comma separated value from `XML` to insert into the table in sql server .

Input:

```
declare @xml xml='
<REQUEST>
  <HEADER>
    <TRAN_ID>101</TRAN_ID>
    <ID_GRP>
      <ID>GO</ID>
      <ID>ZZ</ID>
    </ID_GRP>
  </HEADER>
  <MESSAGE>
    <RATE_CHANGE>
      <RATE_CHANGEID>1122</RATE_CHANGEID>
      <NAME_GRP>
        <NAME>XCX</NAME>
        <NAME>XCH</NAME>
        <NAME>XCR</NAME>
      </NAME_GRP>
    </RATE_CHANGE>
    <RATE_CHANGE>
      <RATE_CHANGEID>1123</RATE_CHANGEID>
      <NAME_GRP>
        <NAME>XCX</NAME>
        <NAME>XCH</NAME>
        <NAME>XCR</NAME>
      </NAME_GRP>
    </RATE_CHANGE>
  </MESSAGE>
</REQUEST>'
```

Query:

```
SELECT  
  E.P.value('(/REQUEST/HEADER/TRAN_ID)[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS 'TRAN_ID',
  E.P.value('(/REQUEST/HEADER/ID_GRP)[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS 'ID_GRP',
  E.P.value('(RATE_CHANGEID)[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS 'RATE_CHANGEID',
  E.P.value('(NAME_GRP)[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS 'NAME_GRP'
from @xml.nodes('/REQUEST/MESSAGE/RATE_CHANGE') AS E(P)
```

Output :

```
TRAN_ID ID_GRP  RATE_CHANGEID   NAME_GRP    
101     GOZZ    1122           XCXXCHXCR    
101     GOZZ    1123           XCXXCHXCR
```

Expected Output :

```
TRAN_ID ID_GRP  RATE_CHANGEID   NAME_GRP    
101     GO,ZZ   1122           XCX,XCH,XCR  
101     GO,ZZ   1123           XCX,XCH,XCR
```

Comment: Your XML keeps changing where each version shows different challenges. Show what you have tried, what the result was and what you would like it to be instead. Right now it is not clear if you need help with parsing the XML or if you don't know how to build a comma separated string using the `for xml path` trick. Both issues have plenty of answers to look at, mainly on Stack Overflow. Have a look at those, try for yourself and come back here when you have a specific question.

Comment: That sounds like a question about how to parse XML using nodes() and value() functions. Try using that yourself and then come back with a new question when you get into trouble.

Comment: @user135088 dude, your sample data keeps changing. Nobody is going to take you seriously at this point. You're probably best off starting a new question, and this time, put your data in there and keep it there. You're asking volunteers to do work for you, but nobody wants to post an answer that will be invalid seconds later when you change the data AGAIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably more efficient ways to solve this, but here is something that may solve your problem.  It works for your sample data, but I have no idea whether it will work for other data.

I used a series of Common Table Expressions to *slice* your `XML`.

This is the '**BASE**' code with the Common Table Expressions. 
I'll be referring to this **BASE** code as I go through my example

```
declare @xml xml='
<REQUEST>
  <HEADER>
    <TRAN_ID>101</TRAN_ID>
    <ID_GRP>
      <ID>GO</ID>
      <ID>ZZ</ID>
    </ID_GRP>
  </HEADER>
  <MESSAGE>
    <RATE_CHANGE>
      <RATE_CHANGEID>1122</RATE_CHANGEID>
      <NAME_GRP>
        <NAME>XCX</NAME>
        <NAME>XCH</NAME>
        <NAME>XCR</NAME>
      </NAME_GRP>
    </RATE_CHANGE>
    <RATE_CHANGE>
      <RATE_CHANGEID>1123</RATE_CHANGEID>
      <NAME_GRP>
        <NAME>XCX</NAME>
        <NAME>XCH</NAME>
        <NAME>XCR</NAME>
      </NAME_GRP>
    </RATE_CHANGE>
  </MESSAGE>
</REQUEST>'

;
WITH ID_GRP
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT E.P.value('(/REQUEST/HEADER/TRAN_ID)[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS 'TRAN_ID'
        ,x1.l1.value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS ID_GRP_ELEMENT
    FROM @xml.nodes('/REQUEST/MESSAGE/RATE_CHANGE') AS E(P)
    CROSS APPLY @xml.nodes('/REQUEST/HEADER/ID_GRP/ID') x1(l1)
    )
    ,ID_GRP_CONCAT
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT TRAN_ID
        ,STUFF((
                SELECT ',' + ID_GRP_ELEMENT
                FROM ID_GRP t2
                WHERE t2.TRAN_ID = t1.TRAN_ID
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 1, '') AS ID_GRP_ELEMENT
    FROM ID_GRP t1
    )
    ,NAME_GRP
AS (
    SELECT t.c.value('(/REQUEST/HEADER/TRAN_ID)[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS 'TRAN_ID'
        ,t.c.value('RATE_CHANGEID[1]', 'INT') AS RATE_CHANGEID
        ,t1.c1.value('.', 'VARCHAR(10)') AS NAME
    FROM @XML.nodes('//REQUEST/MESSAGE/RATE_CHANGE') AS t(c)
    CROSS APPLY t.c.nodes('NAME_GRP/NAME') AS t1(c1)
    )
    ,NAME_GRP_CONCAT
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT TRAN_ID
        ,RATE_CHANGEID
        ,STUFF((
                SELECT ',' + [NAME]
                FROM NAME_GRP t2
                WHERE t2.TRAN_ID = t1.TRAN_ID
                    AND t2.RATE_CHANGEID = t1.RATE_CHANGEID
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 1, '') AS NAME_GRP_ELEMENT
    FROM NAME_GRP t1
    )
```

Now, using the **BASE** code

```
SELECT * FROM ID_GRP
```

gives us

```
| TRAN_ID | ID_GRP_ELEMENT |
|---------|----------------|
| 101     | GO             |
| 101     | ZZ             |
```

We need to concatenate this together.
Again, using the **BASE** code,

```
SELECT * FROM ID_GRP_CONCAT
```

gives us

```
| TRAN_ID | ID_GRP_ELEMENT |
|---------|----------------|
| 101     | GO,ZZ          |
```

Now, let's work on getting the NAME_GRP elements.
Again, using the **BASE** code

```
SELECT * FROM NAME_GRP
```

gives us

```
| TRAN_ID | RATE_CHANGEID | NAME |
|---------|---------------|------|
| 101     | 1122          | XCX  |
| 101     | 1122          | XCH  |
| 101     | 1122          | XCR  |
| 101     | 1123          | XCX  |
| 101     | 1123          | XCH  |
| 101     | 1123          | XCR  |
```

For *each* RATE_CHANGEID group, we need to concatenate the NAME.
Again, using the **BASE** code

```
SELECT * FROM NAME_GRP_CONCAT
```

we get

```
| TRAN_ID | RATE_CHANGEID | NAME_GRP_ELEMENT |
|---------|---------------|------------------|
| 101     | 1122          | XCX,XCH,XCR      |
| 101     | 1123          | XCX,XCH,XCR      |
```

Now, let's pull everything together using a CROSS JOIN

Again, using the **BASE** code

```
SELECT ID_GRP_CONCAT.TRAN_ID
    ,ID_GRP_ELEMENT as ID_GRP
    ,RATE_CHANGEID
    ,NAME_GRP_ELEMENT AS NAME_GRP
FROM ID_GRP_CONCAT
CROSS JOIN NAME_GRP_CONCAT;
```

gives us this (which, I believe, is what you wanted)

```
| TRAN_ID | ID_GRP | RATE_CHANGEID | NAME_GRP    |
|---------|--------|---------------|-------------|
| 101     | GO,ZZ  | 1122          | XCX,XCH,XCR |
| 101     | GO,ZZ  | 1123          | XCX,XCH,XCR |
```

Since you *may* run into performance problems using multiple CTE's against multiple nodes, you *might* get a performance boost if you *materialize* the results of *each* CTE into a local temp table.  Here is a complete example using your original data

```
declare @xml xml='
<REQUEST>
  <HEADER>
    <TRAN_ID>101</TRAN_ID>
    <ID_GRP>
      <ID>GO</ID>
      <ID>ZZ</ID>
    </ID_GRP>
  </HEADER>
  <MESSAGE>
    <RATE_CHANGE>
      <RATE_CHANGEID>1122</RATE_CHANGEID>
      <NAME_GRP>
        <NAME>XCX</NAME>
        <NAME>XCH</NAME>
        <NAME>XCR</NAME>
      </NAME_GRP>
    </RATE_CHANGE>
    <RATE_CHANGE>
      <RATE_CHANGEID>1123</RATE_CHANGEID>
      <NAME_GRP>
        <NAME>XCX</NAME>
        <NAME>XCH</NAME>
        <NAME>XCR</NAME>
      </NAME_GRP>
    </RATE_CHANGE>
  </MESSAGE>
</REQUEST>'

--Drop temp tables if they exist
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ID_GRP') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #ID_GRP
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ID_GRP_CONCAT') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #ID_GRP_CONCAT
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#NAME_GRP') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #NAME_GRP
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#NAME_GRP_CONCAT') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #NAME_GRP_CONCAT

--Create the #ID_GRP temp table
SELECT * INTO #ID_GRP FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT E.P.value('(/REQUEST/HEADER/TRAN_ID)[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS 'TRAN_ID'
        ,x1.l1.value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS ID_GRP_ELEMENT
    FROM @xml.nodes('/REQUEST/MESSAGE/RATE_CHANGE') AS E(P)
    CROSS APPLY @xml.nodes('/REQUEST/HEADER/ID_GRP/ID') x1(l1)
) ID_GRP

--Create the #ID_GRP_CONCAT temp table
SELECT * INTO #ID_GRP_CONCAT FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT TRAN_ID
        ,STUFF((
                SELECT ',' + ID_GRP_ELEMENT
                FROM #ID_GRP t2
                WHERE t2.TRAN_ID = t1.TRAN_ID
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 1, '') AS ID_GRP_ELEMENT
    FROM #ID_GRP t1
) ID_GRP_CONCAT

--Create the #NAME_GRP temp table
SELECT * INTO #NAME_GRP FROM
(
    SELECT t.c.value('(/REQUEST/HEADER/TRAN_ID)[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS 'TRAN_ID'
        ,t.c.value('RATE_CHANGEID[1]', 'INT') AS RATE_CHANGEID
        ,t1.c1.value('.', 'VARCHAR(10)') AS NAME
    FROM @XML.nodes('//REQUEST/MESSAGE/RATE_CHANGE') AS t(c)
    CROSS APPLY t.c.nodes('NAME_GRP/NAME') AS t1(c1)
) NAME_GRP

--Create the #NAME_GRP_CONCAT temp table
SELECT * INTO #NAME_GRP_CONCAT FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT TRAN_ID
        ,RATE_CHANGEID
        ,STUFF((
                SELECT ',' + [NAME]
                FROM #NAME_GRP t2
                WHERE t2.TRAN_ID = t1.TRAN_ID
                    AND t2.RATE_CHANGEID = t1.RATE_CHANGEID
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 1, '') AS NAME_GRP_ELEMENT
    FROM #NAME_GRP t1
) NAME_GRP_CONCAT

--pull everything together using a CROSS JOIN
SELECT #ID_GRP_CONCAT.TRAN_ID
    ,ID_GRP_ELEMENT as ID_GRP
    ,RATE_CHANGEID
    ,NAME_GRP_ELEMENT AS NAME_GRP
FROM #ID_GRP_CONCAT
CROSS JOIN #NAME_GRP_CONCAT;
```

Comment: Is there any chance to get this output without CTE ...because i'm having more than 10 group nodes like <NAME_GRP>,<DESC_GRP>....If try with CTE's for all groups..it is taking long time to execute and throwing the error "The query takes long time ,Please simplify the query ".so if any alternative method is there that would be helpful for me ...thank you

Comment: Assuming you can use a stored procedure to encapsulate the logic, my only suggestion would be to put the intermediate results of each CTE into local temp tables and join the temp tables together a the very end.  As I indicated in my answer, there may be more efficient ways of solving this problem but my answer was the best way I could think of - good luck :)

Comment: if it is possible can you please explain in detail how to store into the local temp tables with the example ...i'm trying ..but not getting any results.thank you

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of using local temp tables.

Comment: I'm glad you found my answer useful :)